# JavaScript Async not working Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

I am new to Wordpress. I have just started the blog in which I can run my HTML / JS code properly. However, When I enter the affiliate code in my post, its not working.

Then I tried it on Local machine simply by just inserting that script but 
It is also not working. 
This is my code -

```
<div data-WRID="WRID-145208114021238062" data-widgetType="staticBanner" data-responsive="yes" data-class="affiliateAdsByFlipkart" height="250" width="300"></div>
<script async src="http://affiliate.flipkart.com/affiliate/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script>
```

I also tried by downloading this script to local machine and then simply giving the link to HTML but no luck.

I know this is something silly but I am not able to figure out. Please help.

Comment: `src="http://affiliate...` `src="https://affiliate...` or `src="//affiliate...` (this last one ONLY if served through a http server)

Comment: Tried that already. Not working.! @JaromandaX

Comment: any errors in your developer tools console, or the network tab of same

Comment: Its not loading that script at all. When I download it on Local, its loading the script but the Div is not displayed. It shows blank screen. Request you to try on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like @Jaromanda was on the right track.

I copy-pasted here in local file and in a local test Wordpress, and the script gets downloaded correctly. It shows an ad for flipkart, I suppose this is the expected behaviour.

To see what the script does, you can pass it through a beautifier to read it more easily.

The downloaded script creates an iframe element and sets the source of the iframe in order to display the ad. But to create the string representing this source, it uses, among other things, the  `window.location.protocol` (see function `createFKWidgetIframe`). The `location` object represents the url of the document in which the script is run, not the location where the script comes from.

This `window.location.protocol` is usually `http:` or `https:`, but if you have it locally and not served through a local http server, then the adress bar in your browser will be something like `file:///C:/path/to/the/file` and the protocol `window.location.protocol` will be `file:`, and even if the iframe gets created, the source of the iframe will be set to something like `file://affiliate.flipkart.com/widget/displayWidget?wrid=...`. This location obviously does not exist. Please have a look at the source code of your page and see what the source of the iframe is set to, to confirm or not.

So if you do not serve the file through a local http server, there is no chance to load the iframe content.

If it also doesn't work on a Wordpress install which you access online, then I'm helpless. I could only advise you to check if you have ad blocker software/plugins or similar on your machine/browser, or if they get blocked by a firewall or a proxy you are behind.

Comment: Ok. So I have to download it to local server and then access it like - 
`<script async src="file://D:/widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script> OR 
<script src="../widgets/FKAffiliateWidgets.js"></script> (async removed)` right ?

Comment: No, not at all. I edited the answer, I hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Appreciate your help on this. It was the issue with blocker plugin on my site itself. I removed them and it is running perfectly. Thanks again for your kind help and support.! :-)